# Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 - not recognized and drivers prevent ability to boot - ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, nvidia-geforce

I have a Dell XPS 15 7509 that I have dual booted with Ubuntu 20.04.
It has a nvidia graphics card: NVIDIA(R) GeForce(R) GTX 1650 4GB GDDR5

However, when I check the settings - about it shows the secondary graphics card.
lvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits) / Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)

Furthermore, when I try to download and use any of the drivers for the nvidia graphics card my computer will no longer boot successfully. It just stays on the black screen with the dell and ubuntu logos and will not progress past it. It requires a hard shut down then to select the driver indicated in the image in recovery mode. All the nvidia drivers in the image cause the boot issue.

Any idea how to utilize the Nvidia Ge Force 1650 graphics card on Ubuntu 20.04 successfully?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I went deep in the rabbit hole on this one, so I'd like to help anyone who experiences the same problem.

This question is very similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192721/properly-installing-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1050ti-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-3-lts?rq=1) one and both the answers are helpful, albeit at the time of writing this post, none of them is accepted.

The answer is well described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-440/+bug/1871041/comments/12) and [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/newly-installed-drivers-are-not-found-when-nvidia-smi-is-called/82686/10). The most important thing is that when you are installing the drivers, and later, while using them, **SecureBoot MUST be disabled**.

**Step By Step Guide**

You need to (step by step):

- (optional) To start clean, you can purge all configs you tried to install so far:

```bsh
sudo apt purge '^.*nvidia*'
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt purge "^.*cublas*"
sudo apt purge "^.*cuda*"
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
sudo apt autoremove
```

- Reboot, and disable `SecureBoot` in the bios. That's extremely important, otherwise the drivers won't load
- After `SecureBoot` is disabled, then you run the following commands:

```bsh
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
reboot
```

- once you reboot, you can verify that your drivers are working by issuing:

```
nvidia-smi
```

**Verify Working Drivers**

If your drivers are working, when you issue `nvidia-smi` you are going to get some output like:

```
Sat Nov 13 17:02:26 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.82.00    Driver Version: 470.82.00    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   50C    P8     2W /  N/A |      9MiB /  3914MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1484      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2041      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Not Working Drivers**

If something went wrong, you are going to see something like:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer for me didn't work entirely because when running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` it would return that my drivers where already installed.

So, I was using Ubuntu 22.04 with NVidia GeForce GTX 1650 and couldn't share screen on Discord. I tried changing to the system recommended driver, but it stopped my PC from booting.

I found a solution and came here to share it.

**how I did it**

1. Start your system on safe mode by holding shift in the initialization
2. run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`
3. run `lspci | grep -i nvidia` just to check if you really have a GeForce GTX 1650. The answer for me was

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M (rev a1)`

This meant I had it and could continue with the proper driver: **nvidia-driver-525**

If you discover that you have another board search for the right driver for it.

4. run on the terminal `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525`

Reboot :)